# UITableView in UIViewController not displaying json?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm building an iOS app using storyboards.I have uitableview in uiviewcontroller and parsing json data which is displaying in table cell.But i'm facing a problem i'm getting json(userid) but it is not displaying in table cell.I have a iboutlet label in tabel cell used to display userid.

here is my code:
In view.h

```
@interface HostDetail : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *UserId;
```

In view.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
[_eventTable reloadData];

_UserId = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://34.100.29.667:3565/api/user/_id/host/:_id/joinrequest"];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if ((unsigned long)data.length > 3) {
    // NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSArray *ys_avatars = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
  if(ys_avatars){
    for (int j=0;j<ys_avatars.count;j++)
        {
        if( ys_avatars[j][@"userid"]==nil ){
             [_UserId addObject: @""];
      }
            else{
                [_UserId addObject:ys_avatars[j][@"userid"]];}
        }}}
else
{
    NSLog(@"asd");
}
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return _UserId.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *Cellidentifier1 = @"eventList";
HostTableCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cellidentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];
 long row = [indexPath row];
cell1.userid.text = _UserId[row];
return cell1;
}
```

Comment: So you've verified that you're getting the JSON, that it deserializes without error (even though you ignore the `error:` parm), and that the data appears in your `_UserId` array?  Have you put breakpoints in your methods to see if `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` are being invoked?

Comment: @HotLicks yes i have put breakpoints in these numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath but it is not invoked that i what i am trying to find out why the code is not going in these methods.

Comment: Are you doing an NSLog on _UserId[row] to make sure its a number?

Comment: So, have you set the delegate and dataSource pointers for the table view?

Comment: Hot Licks yes i have set delegates in .h @interface HostDetail : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

Comment: @Aggressor if it is a no. or string what matters i'm not getting your point

Comment: Is there data there is my question

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by set delegates in

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.table.dataSource = self;
self.table.delegate = self;}
```